# Anyway to increase HTTP Timeout in JBoss?

Tags: jboss5.x

I have a report which takes too long to send a response back to server. In the JBoss Server is it possible to increase the timeout value of the http response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm wrong JBoss 5.x uses Tomcat 6 as its http layer, so you can configure the various timeout values using the config options [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html#Common_Attributes). The actual Tomcat instance is in the subdirectory `deploy/jbossweb.sar` in the JBOSS_HOME folder, and once that gets unpacked you should be able to edit the server.xml file and add the appropriate configuration settings for the various timeouts.